# Go to the end of the C++ function in Vim

Tags: c++, vim

If I am in the middle of the function,  I would like go to the very end of it in vim. I  run into this problem as we sometimes have function of 500+ lines long (don't ask why).

I use vim, gvim.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the "]}" command. You may have to repeat it depending on how nested you are.

Comment: the OP may also want to investigate the '%' command, which jumps to the opening or closing brace/paren/bracket that is paired with whatever is under the cursor.

Comment: Yes, % is useful as well but not for a quick jump out of a large function.

Comment: You might also be interested in [[ and ]], they take you to the beginning of a function or the start of the next function.

Answer (score 31):

`][` goes to the next '}' in the first column.

Read `:help 29.3` to find out more about moving through a program.

Comment: I found your solution more generic than the accepted solution, because the accepted solution didn't work for me in JavaScript.

Comment: Although thinking about it, if it goes to the next '}' in the first column, then it might find difficulty with nested functions.

Answer (score 11):

][ or [] will do this for you.

Comment: but only if the function's opening and closing curly braces are the first character on the line.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using :split and code folding to your advantage - keep a folded view at the top of the screen, unfold a function, split, edit the function, close the split window, collapse the fold.

Comment: This one is also good, but to be honest, I didn't like folding in Vim so far, I just feel it is hard, probably I need to spend some time reading about it, which I don't have unfortunately. Do you have any quick suggestion to make me like it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

SHIFT+5 toggles between { and }.  You can use it to identify the top most block of code.

Comment: I believe that's % which shifts :-)

Comment: Yes... but to make it simpler I used this approach :)

Comment: @MighMoS, this seems to be better for certain cases, because `%` only works if you are on the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I found that @Ana Betts's answer is the most helpful after gone through nearly an hour of "research" . I tried to add some buffer mappings to make perfection:

```
autocmd BufReadPre *.js nnoremap <buffer> [[ []%0
autocmd BufReadPre *.js nnoremap <buffer> ]] ][%0
```

And this to your .vimrc and type `]]` or `]]` to see magic happen :)