# Vim : Moving Through Code

Tags: javascript, python, vim, code-navigation

I want to be able to navigate the cursor across functions using Vim. Mainly, I want a command to allow me to go to the next function, like `}` allows me to go to the next paragraph. I found this:

[Go to the end of the C++ function in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674930/go-to-the-end-of-the-c-function-in-vim)

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work fine in JavaScript. Also, I believe it would also not work for Python, as Python don't depend much on { and }.

Any help?

Comment: `/^def ` will take you to the next top level function

Comment: This is only useful in Python, I am also looking for JavaScript and languages with similar syntax. Besides that, it is easier to press few keys, then to have to make a search every time, but it is good, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

In a Python file I find:

- `}` will take me to the end of a block,
- `]]` will take me to the start of the next function.
- `[[` takes me to the start of the current function, or the one above if I keep pressing.

`]}` didn't seem to work though.